# Detect different lines executed with lcov?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, code-coverage, lcov

I have minimal input that causes my program to fail and a one line hack to restore the correct result. I don't know why the better numbers make my program fail. Is there an easy way to use lcov to compare the two different executions? Most likely the problem is a single branch. I was going to eyeball two pages generated by genhtml but I thought I should ask here if there is there a better way? a llvm-cov solution would be acceptable

Comment: I'd use a debugger, rather than looking at *post mortem* llvm-cov output.

Comment: Have a look at this guide - it will help you get more useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask